# How to identify whether a web server supports Web Services or not?

Tags: java, web-services, webserver

I am not much aware about the details as to which web servers support Web services written in Java.

Would Like to know the following three things:

1) What is required to have support for Web Services : Only Servlet Container or An Application Server + Web container?

2) Would like to know that do all Web Server supporting web development in Java support Web Services?

3) How to identify whether a particular server supports Web Services or not?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: You can check the release documents on each application server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear. The term *web service* is applied to anything from a REST style API to SOAP based services to JSON based, etc etc. Wikipedia says an equivalent is a [Web API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service), and an API can be pretty much anything.

So to answer your question. A servlet container is enough to support most common types of web services, it doesn't require an application server. Take a look at [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/), which is a framework catering for a lot of web services styles (notably SOAP and REST).

Apache CXF is a rather large framework, and can take some time to get your head around. If you need something simpler, you may be better off looking at some object serialization frameworks and implement the servlets yourself (this is what I do mostly). To serialize to XML, use out-of-the box Java JAXB annotations. To serialize to JSON, use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I wish to use JAX-RPC style SOAP based web services.. Would like to know as to how can I identify whether a web server supports JAX-RPC SOAP based web services? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any servlet container should be able to do that. Use Apache Axis http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html - which provides JAX-RPC and run it in Tomcat/Jetty/Weblogic etc... doesn't require an application server, just a servlet container.

Comment: @mahendra:JAX-RPC is the old J2EE spec for web services.Has been replaced with JAX-WS spec

Comment: Note that e.g. Metro (enclosed in Java 6+) requires an additional configuration xml file when deploying in a servlet 2.5 container.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about SOAP WS-* web services via JAX-WS.

Java EE 5+ stipulates support for JAX-WS compatible web services within the container, both at the Web App level, and at the EJB level. So, any full boat, modern, App Server will have JAX-WS support built in.

Servlet 2.x and 3.0 do not have a requirement to support JAX-WS at the container level, but all of the major implementation of JAX-WS can be deployed within a WAR in a modern Servlet container (like Tomcat).

Java EE 6 offers a Web Profile, but the Web Profile does not include JAX-WS. Java EE 6 Full Profile includes both JAX-WS (SOAP, WS-* web services), and JAX-RS (for HTTP and more RESTful web services).

So.

If you bundle your own implementation, all of the containers should accommodate you. If you want it built it to the container, you'll need a full Java EE 5 or Java EE 6 App Server.

Comment: my basic concern is that it should be lightweight and should support SOAP Web Services written in Java. Can you comment?